# Passing data to ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller

I am struggling with the following issue:

I have a `ViewController` and a separate`UIView` attached to it which I use instead of storyboard or xib/nib, meaning I took the "drawing views programatically" approach.

```
class MyViewControllerA: UIViewController {
override func loadView() { 
        self.view = MyViewControllerAView()
    }
}
```

The above works all fine.

Then within my `MyViewControllerAView` I am using a third party UI component which loads two `UIViewControllers` within the `MyViewControllerA` by using a delegate:

```
class MachineHomeView: UIView, ThirdPartyUIComponentDelegate {

        //code ...

        func thirdPartyUIComponent(_ thirdPartyUIComponent: ThirdPartyUIComponent, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
            switch index {
            case 0:
                return MyViewControllerC()
            case 1:
                return MyViewControllerC()
            //..more code
            }
        }
    }
```

And the UI looks like:

[image]

In a nutshell, I have a `ViewControllerA` whose `View` loads two additional ViewControllers - `ViewControllerB` and `ViewControllerC`

As you see I am trying to follow the MVC approach by separating the `View` and the `Controller` from each other.

**The problem** I am facing is that I would like pass data from `MyViewControllerA` to `MyViewControllerB` and `MyViewControllerC`.

The first thing that comes up to my mind is to create a property in the `MyViewControllerAView` e.g callled `test`. So in `viewWillLoad` or `viewDidLoad` I can pass stuff to it like:

`self.view.test = "some data"`

Then in the delegate where I instantiate the two additonal view controllers I can do:

```
func thirdPartyUIComponent(_ thirdPartyUIComponent: ThirdPartyUIComponent, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
                switch index {
                case 0:
                     let myViewControllerB = MyViewControllerB()
                     myViewControllerB.someProperty = self.test
                    return myViewControllerB
                case 1:
               let myViewControllerC = MyViewControllerC()
                     myViewControllerC.someProperty = self.test
                    return myViewControllerC
                }
            }
        }
```

In my mind going the above way is breaking the MVC convention because the View is no longer UI responsible only. Therefore I want to avoid that and keep the MVC clean.

Any ideas of how pass data from `MyViewControllerA` to `MyViewControllerB` and `MyViewControllerC` without breaking the MVC pattern or introducing a bad practice ?

Comment: That is where the "M" part of MVC comes in - the model; Each view controller should have access to the same model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should approach the problem in a following manner.

Move the `thirdPartyUIComponent(_:)` method out of `MyViewControllerAView` to the `MyViewControllerA` - I don't think it's appropriate for the view in MVC to instantiate and handle view controllers. Now the `MyViewControllerA` view controller would be responsible for view controllers `B` and `C`.

Then, since I expect that you need to access the views of `B` and `C` in the `MyViewControllerAView`, pass them directly to the `MyViewControllerAView` - however, pass only views of `B` and `C`, not the view controllers themselves.

This way the `A` view controller will manage view controllers `B` and `C`, but the `MyViewControllerAView` will still have access to the `B.view` and `C.view` to lay them out properly.

P.S.: If the `thirdPartyUIComponent(_:)` callback should be called when some UI action is triggered by the user on the `MyViewControllerAView`, then use the delegate pattern to pass that event to the `MyViewControllerA` to handle it cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

UView shouldn't create UIViewControllers and manage them itself. Make **ViewControllerA** responsible for managing **ViewControllerB** and **ViewControllerC**. Great way to do this is make **B** and **C** child view controllers of A. You can communicate with parent view controller **A** by delegate. 
Apple tutorial how to make this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

However @Milan solution is ok too.